# Integração de python com C#

Tags: c#, python, python-3.x

Existe alguma forma de integrar C# e Python 3?

Preciso criar aplicação gráfica de forma prática e rápida.

Atualmente, tenho os scripts em Python funcionando 100%, agora o que eu preciso é tirar os inputs do terminal e jogar em uma aplicação visual e tinha pensado em utilizar o C# para criá-las já que tenho afinidade com esta ferramenta.

Comment: Você também pode criar WS Local para fazer a conversa entre os dois sistemas.

Comment: Se tiver interesse, eu creio que seja possível continuar usando o Python sem nem alterar os `input`s nem `print`s, através de `named pipes`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/aa365590(v=vs.85).aspx ; estou mais acostumado a fazer isso em sistemas *nix, mas serve para Windows também. Me responda que amanhã ou depois eu escrevo como se usaria `named pipes` neste caso

Comment: Cara, eu fiquei interessado nesse lance de **named pipes** e a aba do google com minha pesquisa já está aberta aqui, mas acho que sua ajuda pode ser muito boa. Se não for pedir demais, tem como você colocar uma resposta pelo menos comentando do assunto e deixando uns links que vc acha interessante sobre esse assunto? Abraço.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Compile tudo em IronPython](http://ironpython.net/). [Tem a versão 3 aqui](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython3).

Procure programar usando classes, para que o .NET reconheça. Depois é só jogar no C#. [Um guia de integração está aqui](http://ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/).